# ¿cómo subir archivos desde un gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Necesito insertar un fileupload en un gridview, tengo el siguiente código pero no funciona

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adjuntar Archivo" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" ShowHeader="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fu1" Text="Adjuntar" runat="server" />
                                    <div id="posicion" style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnguardar" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-xs" runat="server" Text="Adjuntar" CommandName="up" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pdf" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" ShowHeader="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDown" runat="server" CommandName="down" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ImageUrl="~/images/pdf.png" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

code back

```
protected void gvradicaIn_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Button btnUp = e.CommandSource as Button;
    if (e.CommandName.ToLower() != "up")
    {
        if (e.CommandName.ToLower() != "down")
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "up")
    {
        FileUpload fu = btnUp.FindControl("fu1") as FileUpload;
        if (fu.HasFile)
        {
                fu.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files") + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fu.PostedFile.FileName);
                lblValida.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "#01DF01");
                lblValida.Text = "Se ha adjuntado el archivo de manera correcta al radicado";
                limpiar();
            }
            else
            {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con una mejor descripción: ¿qué es lo que no funciona, tienes errores, qué vas a hacer con la imagen que seleccionaste?. te recomiendo además encerrar tu código en un bloque `try/catch`.

Comment: Trabajar con FileUpload  en la misma grilla no se si sea una buena idea. Lo más simple seria abrir una ventana modal y desde ahí adjuntar el documento.